# Trying to read VIEWS in SQL but getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-view

Instance version 9.0.3042

Instance is on white circle instead of green, however that should not be any concern.

I have full access to the database, but I don't understand why I am able to read only couple of views but not the other VIEWS. 
By right click on view and select Top 1000 rows.

The Error I am getting is:

( Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. )

I found out the problem that only reason I am not able to connect is because of the linked server, it connects to different linked server and which I don't have access to. My other question is how do I identify which linked server it connects to?

any possible explanation.

Comment: How to do execute the sql?  Which user? From an external application?

Comment: But which user do  you connect with?

Comment: Are you using a linked server?

Comment: I just edit to my question, Yes it has to do with link server but how do i check which link server it is?

Comment: Post the code of the view.

Comment: I got it, within the code, I noticed the linked server name, thats where I have to go to and members to give him a access to read.